# How to prove the siginicance difference level in this data?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance

I have collected a set of data of 52 weeks of actual output and demand.

Actual
 1100
1300
1400
1500
1600
1100
1200
1600
2100
1300
1600
1300
1600
2200
2300
1700
1800
800
1400
900
2100
1400
1800
1900
1000
1800
1700
2100
800
1100
900
1600
1700
1400
1100
1200
1700
900
700
900
1300
700
1500
700
1300
1100
1700
1600
1800
2000
1500
2100

Demand
1500
2100
1600
1500
2000
1600
1200
2000
2200
2000
2200
2000
2000
2500
2500
2000
2000
1000
2000
1500
2500
1500
2500
2500
2000
2000
2500
2500
1500
1500
1400
2000
2000
2000
1500
1500
2500
1500
1500
1500
2500
1500
2000
1500
1500
2000
2000
2500
2500
2500
2500
2500

Now I am having question in what test should I used and I I found out that one is normally distributed and the other one is not.

Comment: Have you considered the Wilcoxon test?  If you are comparing the means between output and demand and the normality assumption is violated you could always just use the [wilcoxon test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test).

Comment: Is that Wilcoxon test is only can be used if output and demand data are both violated the normality assumption ? Or it can just be used when either one violate the normality assumption?

Comment: Are your weeks sequential? Ie, week1 A D, then week2 A D..., etc. You will almost certainly have serial correlation, which needs to be taken into account or your answer will be incorrect.

Comment: Yes, they are sequential... From 1st week - 52nd week.... Now I got to prove the actual output are having a significant difference compared to the demand. I have no idea where to start with.... any guidance?

Comment: Given the sequential aspect, which I regrettably overlooked, you may want to look into repeated measures anova.  The [Friedman test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test) is typically considered the nonparametric equivalent.

Comment: Before I used the test, how do i prove the data is non-parametric set?

Comment: What are you trying to find out from these data?

Comment: I want to find out the significance difference between these two sets of data. But before conducting the test,i have to do the normality test on data first. Am i on the right track ?

Comment: @koksiang100, This is a different question from what you initially asked.  Testing for normality has been asked [before](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115610/normality-test-for-repeated-measures-data).  There are many methods as well as just visually inspecting the distributions.

Comment: To be specific, I got p=0.415 for my ACTUAL OUTPUT data set( which is normally distributed) , however for demand data set, my p value is < 0.005 ( not normally distributed ). 

And now I don't know which test should I used ? Besides that, how to differentiate for the parametric / non-parametric ?

Comment: @whuber

Is this suitable to use Mann-whitney test to test the significance difference? 

Any assumption I need to make before I use this test?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion: For each week compute the difference between demand and supply (production), then analyze that list of 52 differences either with a one sample t test or a Wilcoxon rank sum test.

But there is no real reason to do any statistics, as Demand exceeds Supply every single week:
[image]