# Multivariate data with repeated measures - restricted permutations

Tags: repeated-measures, multivariate-analysis, permutation-test, ecology

I have a data frame of multivariate abundances (species) that have been measured from sites under two different treatments.  These same sites have been repeatedly measured over multiple years.

I am modelling the change in species abundances between treatments over time using the `mvabund` package in R.  My model is `abundance~treatment*year`.

However, because the same sites have been sampled repeatedly they are repeated measures and thus are not independent between years.  I want to account for this in my model by restricting the permutations using the `permute` package.

However, I am struggling to conceptually understand how I need to restrict the permutations to account for this non-independence.

Comment: Why not just use a mixed effects model?

Comment: Because the data are multivariate, I don't think theres a way to fit mixed effects models to multivariate data? Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Also, @gung, do you know if the OP's point about multivariate species abundance data preclude using mixed effects models?

Comment: @theforestecologist, you would either need to find an existing package for multivariate mixed effects models, you would write out the full likelihood & optimize it yourself, or you would add dummies for the various components of the response (cf, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13197/)).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your design is in the dataframe df and community counts in com

```
permID <- shuffleSet(n=nrow(df), nset=99, control=how(block=df$year))

mod1 <- manyglm(com ~ treatment, family="negative.binomial")
mod2 <- manyglm(com ~ treatment*year, family="negative.binomial")

anova(mod1, mod2, bootID = permID)
```

I think this will work. Any other suggestions?