# Repeated measures ANOVA or MANOVA (SPSS)

Tags: anova, spss, manova

I have an experimental design of two independent groups (pregnant/non-pregnant), in which each person has described past memories and future episodes on different variables on a scale from 1-7. Therefore I have the same variable (vividness for example) measured during remembrance and during construction of the future scenario. I treat the past and future as two separate variables. In this case with two groups, who differ on one categorical variable would it be best to use repeated measures ANOVA or MANOVA?

Comment: Read, for example, this question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13197/3277.

Answer (score 0):

You have one input (2 categories).

- If one output variable, then you may use t-test or ANOVA.
- If 2 (or more) output variables, then you may use MANOVA.